# Rational Picard group of a quotient variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a smooth quasiprojective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and that $G$ is a finite group acting on $X$. Let $Y = X/G$

Let $\text{Pic}\ Y$ denote the Picard group of $Y$ and let $A^1(Y)$ denote the Chow group of codimension 1 cycles on $Y$ mod rational equivalence. Is it true that $\text{Pic}\ Y \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong A^1(Y)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Question answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252792/rational-picard-group-of-a-quotient-variety?noredirect=1#comment622006_252792